# Read files async C

Tags: c, fopen, fs

So it has been few hours since i am learning C and i ran in to a problem with nested functions. i already made Async reading working but want to get read of all helper function by nesting it in a caller function just like that.

```
void ReadFileAsync(struct RA_Data *info)
{

    void *ReadFileAsync_Helper(void *data_struct)
    {

        FILE *fp;
        int len;

        struct RA_Data *info = (struct RA_Data *) data_struct;

        fp = fopen(info->Path, info->Mode);
        if(fp == NULL)
        {
            perror("Error Opening File!");
            exit(1);
        }

        fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);

        len = ftell(fp);

        rewind(fp);

        char *buffer = (char *) malloc(len);

        fread(buffer, len, 1, fp);

        fclose(fp);

        info->callback(buffer);
    }


    pthread_t tid;
    pthread_create(&tid, NULL, ReadFileAsync_Helper,(void *) info);
}
```

it works if u pretend Helper function was declared outside of it. what is wrong with it and how can i solve this ?

Comment: Standard C does not allow nested functions.

Comment: where can i get extension from ? and is there any other way to make function inaccessible ?

Comment: There are no nested functions in C.  You could consider instead declaring the helper functions `static`; that will limit their visibility to the translation unit (roughly, the source file) in which they are defined.

Comment: If you are just learning C I suggest staying with standard C, only when you get proficient look for extensions.

Comment: also another question. in pthread_create i can specify only 1 arg at the end like i did (packed everything in to struct) or i can put more args ?

Comment: It is time to start reading man pages, is better than the scatter gun approach.

Comment: @AntonStafeyev, pthread_create accepts one parameter for the creating thread -- a pointer to void. You may use it to pass the pointer to struct or something else.

Comment: @AntonStafeyev, `pthread_create()` is not a variadic function.  That is, it accepts a fixed number of arguments.  Your usage of it appears canonical as far as it goes, but you really ought to check the return value to ensure that the call succeeds (and to handle the case where it doesn't).  Also, it is questionable, albeit not necessarily wrong, that you neither join the thread, nor report back its id so that the caller can do so, nor detach it.

Comment: i am prototyping it atm. so not adding to many error handlers, so code is readable. i use sleep to simulate main thread process:)

Comment: About detaching, it is done to release all resources back to system. doesnt all resources released when thread is done ?